# Marklogic and Triples

Tags: marklogic, triples

I have a marklogic database with multiple collections. There are relations between collections in the marklogic database. I would like to insert triples to express those relations. Is there a way to insert triples between collections?

Answer (score 1):

Collections in MarkLogic are merely labels on documents. That doesn't have to stop you from using collection names as (subject) iris. Ideally, those collection names look like real iris (something starting with http and such).

HTH!